# Mechanize unable to navigate KBB.com, get Mechanize::ResponseCodeError: 500 => Net::HTTPInternalServerError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mechanize

Trying to navigate KBB.com using Mechanize. I create a new agent

```
agent = Mechanize.new
```

works fine.

```
page = agent.get('http://www.kbb.com/toyota/mr2/1993-toyota-mr2/
styles/?intent=buy-used')
```

returns the page.

```
page.link_with(:text => "Choose this style").click
```

gives me this

```
page.link_with(:text => "Choose this style").click
Mechanize::ResponseCodeError: 500 => Net::HTTPInternalServerError for 
http://www.kbb.com /toyota/mr2/1993-toyota-mr2/coupe-2d/options/?
vehicleid=11263&intent=buy- used&pricetype=&path=&filter= -- unhandled response
```

works fine on craigslist. Why not kbb?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to reproduce this, it looks like one of the cookies is corrupted.   Any additional request fails.

You can work around this by clearing out the cookie jar before each request.

`agent.cookie_jar.clear!`

Comment: I ran the code in IRB, reproduced the failure.  I ended up rerunning the `agent.get` and noticed the failure again.  I realized the first request worked, but subsequent requests failed.   Then I looked up how to clear cookies.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem on a simple form (site: http://www.myresaleweb.com/). It turns out I had accidentally swapped two of the field values when submitting through Mechanize, which caused this particular site to throw the 500 response code error. When I fixed the two values then it worked right away.

The reason I couldn't replicate it on the browser was that I was doing it correct manually. Once I attempted it incorrectly manually (just to confirm the error) then I was able to reproduce the 500 error code via the browser.